# Proof of global Peano existence theorem in ZF without mathematical logic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logic, reference-request, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

There is a proof of Peano existence theorem in ZF.

Peano existence theorem:

> For any open $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, continuous $f:D \to \mathbb{R}$ and initial condition $\langle t_0,x_0\rangle \in D$, there is an open interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $t_0 \in I$ and a differentiable function $X: I \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $X(t_0)=x_0$ and $X'(t) = f(X(t),t)$ for all $t \in I$, and no strictly larger $I_\ast \supset I$ has such a function extending $f$.

reference: https://mathoverflow.net/a/455875

The proof in the link uses a theorem in mathematical logic called Shoenfield absoluteness to automatically translate ZFC proofs of low quantifier complexity statements about countably coded objects to ZF proofs.

I am not familiar with mathematical logic and advanced set theory, nor do I understand Shoenfield absoluteness. Even if I understand it, I expect the proof generated by automatic translation to be not very human readable.

Is there a proof of this theorem in ZF that can be understood by an undergraduate student who is not a set theory major?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are requiring that there is no strictly larger interval on which a solution would be defined, you are talking about the *global* version of Peano's existence theorem.  This was proved in ZF (without choice) without using Shoenfield absoluteness in the following recent publication:

> Hrbacek, K.; Katz, M. "Peano and Osgood theorems via effective infinitesimals." *Journal of Logic and Analysis* **15**:6 (2023), 1-19.
> https://doi.org/10.4115/jla.2023.15.6
> https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.01374